# SQL: Calling REPLACE() with a NULL replacement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've recently run into this behaviour and whilst I can work around it, I'm quite curious as to why it occurs. There doesn't seem to be much documentation explaining why this happens.

Consider the following two snippets:

```
SELECT REPLACE('hello world', 'world', NULL)    
SELECT REPLACE('hello world', 'foobar', NULL)
```

Both of these examples return NULL.

I don't really understand either, but with the first one I can see how if there is indeed some caveat I'm unaware of with NULLs that this will cause the outcome we see.

But with the second example I'm completely stumped. Even if there is some strange NULL replacing behaviour, why is my string being manipulated at all? The replacement string is not found in the target string.

Comment: The [documentation for replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) clearly states that it _Returns NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL._ It's listed in the second paragraph under **Return Types**

Comment: Downvote reason: Please read the documentation, especially if your question complains about it.

Comment: Replacing any part of a string with `NULL` is not a meaningful operation to begin with. Think of it as the function validating its arguments, seeing something invalid and immediately bailing out.

Comment: I'm going to take a stab at why this is the case, but I don't have any proof and can't find evidence. You would think they would look for the string and replace it if found, but most high performing things are done by bit comparisons, shifting, OR'ing, or AND'ing. My bet would be that behind the scenes, they are AND'ing the string (or parts of it) at a binary level. Doing this with NULL results in NULL.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean: since `REPLACE` has to take collations into account for matching string contents, that is almost certainly not how it works. `SELECT REPLACE('a' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'á' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'b')` isn't going to do any bit twiddling. In general, basic T-SQL operations are not optimized to extreme levels because it doesn't pay off (I/O dominates). Things change when you start to consider memory-optimized tables and native compilation.

Comment: @JeroenMostert But how would that explain how a string not found would be replaced with NULL as the second scenario in the question shows?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean: consider the possibility that it's implemented exactly how the documentation says it is: `if (isNull(arg1) || isNull(arg2) || isNull(arg3)) return DB_NULL; /* all arguments are non-NULL, do regular replacement */`. Getting the special cases out of the way greatly simplifies things. (And note that `NULL` is not the null terminator or an otherwise blank string, so it is a special case.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert That is a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

It states that:

> Returns NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

This is most certainly a result of the messed up NULL handlich in SQL Server. Everything you perform with NULL will result in NULL as well. Try SELECT 1 + NULL or 'abc' + NULL. Anyways, since you are working with a string, you should use the empty string '' instead of NULL.

Comment: SQL Server is handling nulls just fine, most of the cases. There are just  few places where you can honestly say it messed things up, such as `order by` and `set ansi-nulls off`.

Comment: We recently had an issue, where a developer left joined some tables - one contained prices and the other one VAT percentages. However, unfortunately he didn't consider, that `PRICE + (PRICE * VAT_Perc)` results in NULL, when his right table doesn't contain a VAT percentage for a given timespan...

Comment: The fact that your developer failed to handle what is a very common situation working with databases does not mean that SQL Server handles nulls wrong...

Comment: Yeah, OK. So the NULL handling is fine - nevertheless, REPLACE should be used with '' instead of NULL :-P

Comment: replace should not be used with `null`, unless you **want** it to return `null`. It's a well documented behavior. Don't go trashing a product because you or your team member failed to read or understand the documentation... I'm not saying SQL Server is bug free, but that this case is not a bug.

Comment: @ZoharPeled but this is exactly what I wrote in my last comment. :-( You are right - from this point of view the NULL handling is correct. Therefore I wrote, that in the Replace statement the empty string '' should be used instead on NULL. So, no trashing of anything in my previous comment.

Comment: I see. Sorry for doubting you.